# Whats link between [__NSSetM objectAtIndex:]: and NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsset

This is my NSMutableArray:

```
tableviewarray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"ca1.png", @"ca2.png", @"ca3.png", @"ca4.png", @"ca5.png", @"ca6.png", @"ca7.png", @"ca8.png",@"ca9.png",@"ca10.png",nil];

NSLog(@"loaded into array =%@",tableviewarray);


loaded into array =(
    "ca1.png",
    "ca2.png",
    "ca3.png",
    "ca4.png",
    "ca5.png",
    "ca6.png",
    "ca7.png",
    "ca8.png",
    "ca9.png",
    "ca10.png"
)
```

and i was printed my array all things added properly

When i tried to use this array in tableview i am getting error :

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"reload+option=%@",tableviewarray);
    TableViewCell *cell;
    cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    cell.images.image=[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[tableviewarray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
    return cell;
}
```

Error:

> reload+option={(  -[__NSSetM objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector
>   sent to instance 0x146c05c0  *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSSetM
>   objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x146c05c0'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x2115c10b 0x20902e17 0x21161925 0x2115f559 0x2108fc08 0xad8eb 0x255da6bd 0x255da7fd 0x255ca031
>   0x255defcb 0x2538285b 0x25294d13 0x23393f99 0x2338f695 0x2338f529
>   0x2338ea49 0x2338e6fb 0x23387ebb 0x2111ef59 0x2111d25d 0x2111d68f
>   0x21070bf9 0x210709e5 0x222bcac9 0x25300ba1 0x9687f 0x20d1f873)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

NSMutableArray Initialising :

```
-(void)viewdidload
{
[super viewdidload];
tableviewarray=[[NSMutablearray alloc]init];
}
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9amE.png): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydFGE.png here i am changed tableviewarray to arrimages

New update for debugger [image]

After change array add object[image] to inside cell for row at index path

Comment: That message says that `tableviewarray` is an NSMutableSet, not an array so it doesn't understand `objectAtIndex`; double check everywhere where you modify `tableviewarray`

Comment: this problem is only occurs when the method enters inside tableviewcellfor row at index path @Paulw11

Comment: Where do you set up your array?  How do you define that variable?  By the time you get to this method it is an NSMutableSet

Comment: add this one and try this if(!cell)
{
  cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
}

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik why would that help?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik bro still giving same error and while entering inside tableviewcell my array is empty ,i verified it well viewdidload method didn't call ,i am initialising my array on viewdidload but how the datas get empty ?

Comment: @Paulw11 -- he use the mutableset not mutablearray , it only crash in reuseable that the reason I added this

Comment: can you update your question bro

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik wait a minute

Comment: Wha is your `numberOfRowsInSection` method?  Where is `tableviewarray` declared? Whereabouts is the first bit of code in your question?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik no access bro :(

Comment: @KishoreKumar, have you alloc two times NSMutableArray ? .. one in viewdidLoad and another with [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"ca1.png", @"ca2.png", @"ca3.png", @"ca4.png", @"ca5.png", @"ca6.png", @"ca7.png", @"ca8.png",@"ca9.png",@"ca10.png",nil]..

Comment: @None yeah so you are saying because of this its crasing ?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik bro i have added image :)

Comment: bro are you showing two seperate array names in here are you showed `tableviewarray` but in your image are you showed `arrImages`, probelm in `arrImages` , can you show the related code it is easy to resolve

Comment: yes bro now i changed tableviewarray to arrImages

Comment: @KishoreKumar, No just i want to give you point regarding memory. have you declare arrImages as week or what ?

Comment: @None thanks >>>:) ,now i understood

Comment: @KishoreKumar, is that a problem?

Comment: @None no bro ,something problem but can't find ,now i am going to leave it everything proper while entering to cellforrow at index path all datas erased from my array ,how is it possible? i printed my array in numberofrow insection also values there :(

Comment: Please post the complete, symbolicated, stacktrace so we can be sure where this is crashing.

Comment: @KishoreKumar [arrImages removeAllObjects];

Comment: Is this program using ARC? If not, the array was probably deallocated and a set happened to be allocated in the same spot.

Comment: We don't know where it's actually crashing as you haven't posted the stacktrace.  I don't believe it's crashing in code you've posted.

Comment: @trojanfoe yes me to can't believe its old code now i am revamp it ,when its entering to cellforrow at index path method ,array datas getting erased.hard to find solution.

Comment: So where is the stacktrace?  How many times do I need to ask for it?

Comment: wait a minute @trojanfoe

Comment: @trojanfoe i have updated you can check it

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik bro i have added new debugger image :)

Comment: @KishoreKumar That looks like a different crash to *unrecognised selector*.

Comment: but your error is showing in different bro

Comment: i need to debug it as soon as possible ,its pretty simple once i find  out the problem :).

Comment: Did you verify that you are using ARC?

Comment: its old code @trojanfoe now i am revamp it and help me how to check it?

Comment: It's really very important you answer this question.  Are you using Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)?  You cannot touch the code until you know if it's using ARC or not, so I cannot believe you don't already know.  You were asked this question over 2 hours ago by Catfish_Man and you failed to answer it.

Comment: @trojanfoe sorry for that :) ,may be i don't know at a time from now i know it i know about the ARC but in xcode i dont know where it placed ,llvm compiler language automatic reference counting =no

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning to tableviewarray. tableviewarray is not a property, it is an instance variable, local variable, or global variable. You didn't follow the essential guideline that instance variables should start with an underscore.

Since you are creating a mutable array, but then get an error saying that you are accessing a set, bets are that your bad style caused you to confuse some variables. At some point you assigned an array to something called tableviewarray. At another point accessing something called tableviewarray gives you a set. That set doesn't turn up by coincidence, miracle, or out of maliciousness, it's there because you stored it there.

Look for compiler warnings. Look where you are using NSSet. Look where you assign to tableviewarray. Remove the declaration of your instance variable and use the property.

When you debug your code, follow the simple rule: It breaks because *you* made a mistake. There's nothing magical happening, it's *your* mistake and all you need to do is find it. Searching and examining uses of NSSet and tableviewarray should get you there.

Comment: yes sure its my mistake only bro ,but i didn't used nsset .

Answer (score 0):

So it seems you are revamping an old app and you didn't even take the time to check if the app uses automatic or manual reference counting before you started hacking away at it.

The fact that you don't understand the implications of ARC is unbelievable and you have wasted a considerable amount of our time.

Code like this:

```
tableviewarray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"..."];
```

will behave very differently under ARC and MRR and will cause all sorts of issues when using manual reference counting.

That is about all I am willing to say at this point.

Comment: yes sorry for that ,this is first time i am doing revamp so i failed ,but here after i will check it A to Z ,you not wasted the time bro ,you teach more for me :)